# Feedback when user click on Safari Push Notification

Tags: javascript, safari, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, safari-push-notifications

I am currently working on implementing **Safari Web Push Notification** and everything works fine. However I would like to get **feedback** from user **who click on the notification** like chrome and firefox does.

I have search threw stackoverflow and the Safari Push Notification documentation, [safari push notification documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1)

but i couldn't find any information related to this subject. Does anybody have a suggestion ?

Comment: Did you find anything on this. ?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't find any information yet.